# How can I open a link\folder contained in a string variable in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

If I have the next simple code:

```
string myVar = @"c:\Files\MyFile.txt"
```

And I want to open the path contained in myVar variable (which means - "c:\Files\MyFile.txt") **while debugging**, I need to:

1. Add myVar to Watch Window
2. Copy the path
3. Open the Run command (WinKey + R)
4. Paste the path
5. Click enter

Is there some shortcut or some Plug-in for opening links/paths that contained in string variables

Comment: Is this something you want in your code or as a debug aide in Visual Studio?

Comment: @ChrisF as a debug aide

Answer (score 0):

Considering you're using visual studio, try this:
`string myVar = @"FILE:///c:\Files\MyFile.txt"`

Visual Studio will consider that a Link and allow you to CTRL + Click to open said file.
This will only work with absolute paths (as far as I know), and will try to open in visual studio, but this is the only simple solution I know of without extensions.